# How do I display an Icon on the Taskbar but not on the form itself?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

If I use `ShowIcon` in the form properties, I get the icon in the top left of my form (I don't want that), but I do get my icon in the taskbar.

If I turn `ShowIcon` off, then I get no icon on the form but I get the default winform icon on the taskbar.

I've tried changing border style, but `FixedToolWindow` creates an undesirable look that doesn't match the style of the other forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround. If you do `Me.ShowIcon = False` *after* the form is loaded, then it will display in the taskbar, but not on the program.

One way to do this is to have a timer enabled/begin as soon as form load ends, and then on tick, do `Me.ShowIcon = False`

As Below:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.ShowIcon = False
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     Timer1.enabled = True
End Sub
```

`Timer1` has an interval of 100ms (which works). If you just put the `ShowIcon` as `True` in the `Form1_Load`, a weird Icon shows (not the program's original icon). This is why we use the Timer.